# How can Java DAO's support old database schema versions

Tags: spring-boot, database-schema, dao, backwards-compatibility

For Example: If i have java DAO's to deal with Database tables, if i release the Dao's and their Manager's as a jar file, if an application having a dependency on this jar has access only to the latest version of this jar, then how does the latest jar deal with backwards compatibility when the database schema has changes.

Eample:
When Dao_1.jar was released ...the database schema was at version V1.0
When Dao_2.jar is released .....the database schema version is v1.1

How can an application using Dao_2.jar deal or interact with the database schema version V1.0?

Answer (score 0):

Technically it can't deal it !! for example , you just add a new field to your Dao_2 entity . but in database schema version V1.0 you don't have that field . so all things going to be chaos after you running your application . you could let your hibernate ( JPA ) configuration update you database schema . in this scenario after running your application , your database schema from V1.0 will change to the current version based on your Dao_2 . but it's kind of risky . The correct approach is you always go through from you Dao to database schema . don't edit your schema separately from your application domain . you make new changes in your application data domain . and then ORM will take care of everything and will update your database schema too .